# Attempting to port face books login button to swift

Tags: objective-c, facebook, swift

Everything seems to be going well, I am following this tutorial: http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-facebook-login-in-swift/#prettyPhoto

However within this function I am filled with errors, I am not sure if this is because of swift 2.0 or not but I am running Xcode 7.0.1
The two errors I am getting below are

```
 Objective-C method 'application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:' provided by method 'application(_:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'application(_:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:)' in protocol 'UIApplicationDelegate'
```

on the first line

as well as this error below on the second to last line of the function

```
Cannot invoke 'handleOpenURL' with an argument list of type '(NSURL, sourceApplication: NSString?)'
```

_

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: NSString?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool{
    var wasHandled:Bool = FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication)
    return wasHandled
}
```

I would also like to mention that I do not understand Objective-C at all

Answer (score 0):

Try this (directly from Facebook's walkthrough of integrating their login button, and what I use in one of my apps that uses Facebook login)

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```